# clojurescript and ember.js

Tags: ember.js, clojurescript

I have 0% `clojurescript` knowledge/experience at this time of writing but I have been using `ember.js` for some time.

I am having a look at `clojurescript` and I was going to try and use them together but then I thought perhaps I don't need `emberjs` if I am using `clojurescript`.  I can use things like `core.async` that would be negated if I used ember perhaps.

**So the question is:**

Do I really need `emberjs` or should I be using something more lightweight like `react.js` or the Om project and try and utilize `clojure` as much as possible?

Answer (score 1):

I've used Om for a significant project, and I'm now working full-time in Ember/coffeescript (clojure someday again :-).

Ember won't give you much above and beyond Om/core.async/cljs except a mostly-coherent integration of app-state with router urls out of the box.

I find its observers, computable properties and OO hierarchy to be a bit hard to reason about, and its integration with the build system also seems an affront to developer flexibility (ember-app-kit).

I'm also not a fan of their 'components' so far, with non-intuitive and boilerplated composition of things like events (actions).  This can easily be done sooo much better with core.async, no more promise/callback hell.

I'm definitely thinking about how to integrate Om into such a codebase, I think a proper shim could be made via Ember's [CoreView](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.CoreView.html) class.  I don't know about the maturity of current CLJS routers, but if they're good enough I would avoid shoehorning these together for a new app.

If there are other things you want from the ember ecosystem, like ember-data, then maybe that would warrant more consideration?

Comment: With the emergence of ember addons and maturation of ember-data over the past 2 years, I think this is becoming much more appealing combination of technologies. Ember appears to be working towards integrating more and more functional paradigms. There's this thread on integrating redux unidirectional data flow into ember: http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/is-hot-reloading-like-redux-in-ember-available/9416 The introduction of ember-concurency, ember-cerebral, etc